# Supporting SSL for multiple catch-all sites in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, virtual-machine, ip-address, wildcard-subdomain

### Scenario

We have a multi-tenant SaaS application deployed on a VM hosted with a service provider. We have multiple domains pointing to this VM (let us call them abc.com and xyz.com). Each of our tenant gets a unique sub-domain URL from one of these domains.

In our IIS installation no domains are explicitly defined - as a result, when a request hits the IIS, as no domains are defined, all requests are automatically routed to the default site.

With this arrangement, we are able to serve a any number of sub-domains for each of the primary domains pointing to the VM without having to explicitly create these sub-domains. For example, t1.abc.com, t2.abc.com, t3.xyz.com, t4.xyz.com are all served by our application without having to create these sub-domains in IIS instance.

In our application, when we get the request, by checking the requested URL, we can easily identify the tenant from which the request is coming. All further data access is automatically restricted to the data created by the particular tenant.

### Issue

We need to provide secure communication to all our application users through SSL. We can purchase wildcard SSL for each of the domains (viz abc.com, xyz.com). Now the issue is, how do we deploy multiple SSLs on a single website/application defined in IIS?

This will require us to have two separate sites defined in IIS for abc.com and xyz.com. Unfortunately, these will not be "catch-all" sites for the corresponding sub-domains. By default, IIS allows only one "catch-all" site.

From what I understand from some of the posts, we can have multiple "catch-all" site (for separate domains) in IIS, provided each of them is bound to a separate IP address. Though I could not find any document providing the steps for the same. Can someone point me to the document / steps for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have 2 separate boxes for `abc.com` and `xyz.com` domains. You can request your CA to combine all DNS records into single SSL certificate with all required [Subject Alternative Names](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/wildcard-san-names.htm) SAN.

We also ran into this problem before and SAN certificate worked really well with our multi-tenant configuration. I would also recommend to use load balancer like [Nginx for SSL offload](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination) to serve your client faster and even more secure. In this case you can just point new client to the Load Balancer.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. From SAN the link you provided, I could not gather how it will help me setup wildcard SSL support for two separate domains. Primarily I am looking at creating multiple "catch all" sites in IIS for one for each specific domain. I think if I can do that, I will be able to install wildcard SSLs for each of these sites. The link http://www.pzxc.com/apache-style-wildcard-hostname-rewrite-rules-in-iis suggests a way using ARR - but when I tried that, the original request URL was lost, so we could not identify the tenant (we rely on request URL to identify the tenant).

Comment: @viklele - the link I've included was just concept description, in terms of setup - you will not be able to do it on your own. You need just to submit support case with your CA (certificate authority like digicert or whatever you use) in order to perform this combination.

Comment: @viklele I am not very familiar with ARP - but this function (passing request based on domain is already well [defined in nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3) via virtual hosts. Furthermore, you can fully delegate ssl offload to nginx as I mentioned before in my answer. On the other hand, you can try ARP solution to see if it works for you.

Comment: I finally solved it by using multiple IP addresses on my Windows 2012 server. IIS 8 (on Win 2012 server) allows creating a catch-all site per IP address available. As my application is on a VM behind a primary firewall, I had to open port 80 and 443 on primary firewall for each of the IP address assigned to my VM.